# How to place two data driven pages on one map layout?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, data-driven-pages, layouts, strip-map

**I need to place two data frames (DF) with different data driven pages (DDP) on one map layout.** i have two different Strip Map Index Features (SMIF) for each data frame.
When i turn next page in DDP series for DF1 this work only for DF1. If i want next DDP in DF2 i need to setup DDP and choose SMIF2.
**Is it possible on one map?**
Dynamic text work only current DDP this is problem too.
P.S. I don`t have Map Atlas Extension.
[image: my map]

Comment: I don't think you can have two DDP on the same map layout. However, with the text you can do a join to one of your DDP-driving layers and use that. I've noticed that too much (>5) DDP-text on the layout severely slows down performance.

Comment: Thanks. You can tell more about dynamic text join on my example.
I have SMIF1 and SMIF2  with field attributes in table. what i need to do? As result i will get two different dyn. text who take attribute from two different feature layers and use one DDP?

Comment: It's no different than any other join you make. Based on spatial relations (Spatial join) or common attributes (Join Field) you can join data to your DDP-layer, which you then can access and display on your layout.

Answer (score 8):

To my understanding it is not possible to have two different data frames each using `data driven pages`. However, there are *methods/tricks* you can employ to emulate this behavior by manipulating properties of the data frame. Specifically the *Extent Indicator* and *Data Frame* tabs of the *Data Frame Properties* dialog.

[image: Data Frame Properties Extent Indicator tab]

For example, in the image above the same layer that is used as the *Index Layer* in the data driven enabled main data frame is also placed in a second data frame shown in the lower right of the page. On the *Extent Indicator* tab of the second data frame (inset map), the *show extent indicators for these data frames* property is set to the main data frame (in this case Surveys) which is currently using `data driven pages`.

[image: Data Frame Properites Data Frame tab]

Then, as in the image, above set the data frame tab *Extent* property to *Automatic* and *Extent Used By Full Extent Command* to *Extent of data in all layers (Default)*. This will cause the inset map to keep its same extent when the going through the data driven pages but have a colored indicator tracking the page of the data driven pages, which are on a much more focused scale.

Although this is an example, manipulating the options on the *Extent Indicator* and *Data Frame* tabs of the *Data Frame Properties* can quasi enable data driven pages for two data frames.

Comment: +1 for extent indicators, didn't think of that one (even though I use it almost every week).

Comment: @JamesSLC You may help me. I'am not sure what i correctly understood how extent indicator work. My map has 3 data frames: 1DF Contain base part of polygon (use DataDrivenPage to show next item); 2DF Contain additional part, but not all basic polygons have this part (use Bookmarks); 3DF This is extent indicator. In theory, I add 1DF and 2DF to "Show extent indicator for these data frames:" in Extent Indicator dialog. But its work only for one DF (1 or 2). Maybe not works becose second DF does not always has extent?